# How to send reply to mail in php

Tags: php

I have created a script which send an email to users with a link on it. I want when user click on that click a email should revert back to send with the confirmation that user has accept the invitation. I am able to send mail to client but how can i get reply from them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get confirmation that they have clicked the link and accepted the invitation then you need to make the link point to your server and include the users id in the url. For example:

```
Click <a href="http://myserver.com/accept_invitation.php?userid=34">here<a/> to accept the invitation.
```

The create the accept_invitation.php script on your server and access the user id by using $_GET['userid']. Then do want you want to do with the accepted invite, store it in the database or send an email to yourself to inform you they have accepted.

Answer (score 0):

- For each email you send, you should create an unique id so you can identify the receiver.
- Then, The link sent by email should have some variable in it, like: www.website.com/landing.php?id=theidyoucreated
- In the landing.php page you should GET that id and use it to identify the user

I hope i've been clear enough, let me know if you need further assistance :)

Answer (score -1):

Firstly There is no reliable way.

E-Mail clients block all of these attempts. You can give them an image that they might want to see and if they read the message, and therefore they choose to display images in their mail client.